# DiscordJs registered command dont show up

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

I want to build a discord bot with slash commands. I use the following script to register the commands:

index.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require("node:fs");
const { REST } = require("@discordjs/rest");
const { Routes } = require("discord-api-types/v9");
const { Client, Intents, Collection, Interaction, ClientUser } = require('discord.js');

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
});

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

const commands = [];
const GUILDID = process.env.GUILDID;

client.commands = new Collection();

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
};

const rest = new REST ({version: "9"}).setToken(process.env.TOKEN);

client.once("ready", () => {    
    console.log("Ready");
console.log(commands);

    const CLIENT_ID = client.user.id;

    (async () => {
        try {
            if(process.env.ENV === "production"){
                await rest.put(Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID),{
                    body: commands
                });
                console.log("Successfully registered commands globally");
            } else {
                await rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(CLIENT_ID, GUILDID), {
                    body: commands
                });
                console.log("Successfully registered commands locally");
            }
        } catch (err) {
            if (err) console.error(err);
        }
    })();
});


client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

I have one command so far called "ping.js" which is in the commands folder, which is in my project  folder.

ping.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("ping")
        .setDescription("pong"),
    async execute(interaction) {
        interaction.reply({
            content: "Pong",
            ephemeral: true
        })
    }
}
```

I also have an .env file in the project folder.

```
ENV=test
TOKEN=****
GUILDID=****
```

The script runs without errors and I get "Successfully registered commands locally" as a feedback, but the command dont show up in Discord. I have tried to register the bot again, restart my PC and the terminal and I have checked the code multiple times.
Whats make this a bit frustrating is that it first works and let me run the ping command, but after adding another command, the new one dont showed up. And now I have deleted the secound command again but cant get back.

Thank you all very much for you help in advance

Update:
Following the advise from Gh0st I have added the line console.log(commands) which gives me the following response:

```
Ready
[
  {
    name: 'ping',
    name_localizations: undefined,
    description: 'pong',
    description_localizations: undefined,
    options: [],
    default_permission: undefined
  }
]
Successfully registered commands locally
```

To me it seems that the for loop works since they are in the array, but they commands still dont show up in Discord.

Comment: I assume the error somwhere in this part, but I have no idea:
`
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"));

const commands = [];
const GUILDID = process.env.GUILDID;

client.commands = new Collection();

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
};

`

Comment: Add `console.log(commands)` right under `console.log(‘Ready’)` and then update your question with what it logs

Comment: @Gh0st It logs the following: `[
  {
    name: 'ping',
    name_localizations: undefined,
    description: 'pong',
    description_localizations: undefined,
    options: [],
    default_permission: undefined
  }
]`
So I assume the for loop works since it get the commands in the array, but they still dont show up in Discord

Comment: So I helped someone that had this issue once and just to make sure, you don’t have another build of this bot (perhaps written in python) that uses the same token, running concurrently do you?

Comment: @Gh0st No it dont have it running elsewhere. I have restarted my PC to ensure that the console is  closed and the bot is offline before running the script. I also tried to reset my token without any effect. I will continue to find the issue and keep you updated. Thank you for your help so far. Can I ask you a question ? Do you thing it makes sens to switch to phyton for discord bots ? I have never worked with phyton but it seems that it is more commenly used.

Comment: I have redone everything from scratch and now it works. Thank you very much for your help. Without your help I would have given up @Gh0st

Comment: it is up to you which language you write it in, and glad you got it fixed